# Google map on Iphone 7 plus iOS 10.1.1 not working

Tags: swift, google-maps, cocoapods, ios10

I have to implement googlemaps in Swift 3 Xcocde 8 with Cocoa Pods. The issue is only with iphone 7 plus rest are working fine.

GoogleMaps (2.1.1)

when i try to load map for this screen it shows blank screen like attached image. Its working fine on all other devices except iphone 7 plus device as well as simulator.

I dont know may be the googlemap SDK for pods is old or what?

Kindly help

[attached image not showing google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdDki.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed by removing coreLocation.framework from my target build Phases.

Map was not showing because I have installed the google map sdk through Pod. There was CoreLocation.framework who was overriding the latest map sdk libraries.